# Can I connect another local MySQL service on WampServer?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a running local mysql windows service. I need wampserver to view data from web. How can I set wamp to connect my own local mysql instead of default mysql service of wamp server? When I open phpMyAdmin I want to connect my own mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can run many MySQL servers on same machine. But **each server instance** must run on different port (the default is 3306).

Put in short, you have to edit your MySQL configuration file (normally called `my.ini`) and set the port (I assume you have installed the servers each in separate folder). Then you will be able to connect to given server by specifying the chosen port.